# Why isn't & working?

Tags: macos, bash, find

So I ran the command `find / .bash_profile` to see if it existed anywhere on my Mac before I create one.  Searching the entire computer obviously takes a minute, so I wanted to run it in the background (something I haven't tried to do before) so I added an `&` to the end, like so: `find / .bash_profile &`

However, instead of running it in the background and letting me do other things, this just made the process uninterruptible! It continued to run in the foreground but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> no longer had any effect; it could only be stopped by closing the terminal instance entirely.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ctl-c had no effect **because** it was running in the background. Keyboard interrupts only affect the foreground job.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, why are you using `find` instead of Spotlight?

Comment: @Barmar - because the command line is the PROPER OS user interface... ;-)

Comment: If you wanted to pauze or break it while it ran in the background (which it did, despite spewing output to the terminal), send a kill (-1 HUP to stop or a suspend/resume. See `kill -l`). Alternatively bring it back to the foreground with `fg` or `fg %jobnumber` (see `jobs`) and then Control-C or Control-Z it.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do this frequently, and don't want to use Spotlight, you could enable the `locate` facility and then use `locate .bash_profile`. If you try that command now, it will tell you how to enable it permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed running in the background and you can do other things, but anytime it outputs something, it outputs to your current terminal.

Suggestion:
`find / -name .bash_profile >my_result.txt 2>/dev/null &`

This saves the output to a file, and discard all errors (such as permission denied error). You can check the status by either peeking in the output file `tail my_result.txt` or by typing `jobs`.

If you need to kill the job, type `kill %1` where 1 is the job number in `jobs`.

Comment: Two more nice things to optionally add to the post:
1) tails -f option
2) bringing it back to the foreground and killing it there (`fg` `control-c`).

+1 for also mentioning stderr.

Comment: What is `2>`? I'm not sure what that's called so I'm not sure how to google it.

Comment: @Aerovistae: `2` is stderr, short for standard error. `2>/dev/null` means that errors are redirected to `/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Found a way to look it up, too. Not sure what `0>` would do though....apparently redirects stdin....which I thought had to use `<`

Comment: @Aerovistae: See [TLDP on I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the process was in the foreground? 
Just because it was writing output to the terminal does not mean it was in the foreground.

If you have a command that produces output, and you want to run it in the background,
you should *redirect* the output, as:

```
find / -name .bash_profile > find_results &
```

It is normal for background process to be immune to interrupts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>),
so you can interrupt your foreground job without interfering with background job(s). 
(Note, BTW, that you got the command wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled on a pet peeve of mine with `find`.  Try using the `-print` option like so

```
find / -name '.bash_profile' -print > some_file
```

You also may be running into an issue by not escaping or single-quoting the dot in the filename. `find` supports RegEx syntax so that dot in the filename could be misinterpreted. Either of the examples below should address this

```
find / -name 'some_file.txt' ...
```

or

```
find / -name some_file\.txt ...
```

Single quotes are more flexible because you do not have to escape **each** control character and you can  more easily encase characters like @ or /

Comment: (2) While it's a good idea to quote constant strings, and essential that you quote strings that contain special characters (or escape the special characters), dot (i.e., period, i.e., `.`) is not a special character in this context. `find … -name` doesn't treat its argument as a full fledged RegEx (see `-regex`) and so it doesn't treat `.` as special. Even if it did (e.g., if we _were_ talking about `-regex`), quoting the string or escaping the character wouldn't matter; you would need to escape the character ***and*** quote the string. And what are you saying about `@` and `/`?

Comment: (1) What's the pet peeve? Why do you believe that saying `-print` explicitly makes a difference? It is the default action ("expression").

Comment: I guess it's a pet peeve because I would have written this so that "print" was the implied default behavior. And while the find may not treat a dot in the regex context, it **could** be misinterpreted as the current directory. I've also had issues with @ needing to be escaped although an example ironically escapes me.